# Can a splash page be enabled for an ArcGIS Online Organization's homepage?

Tags: arcgis-online

I am working with an established ArcGIS Organization account. I'm looking to push out communication to all users and would rather not go the route of emailing all users.

Is it possible to have a splash screen at the homepage or Gallery page of our ArcGIS Online organization account in order to communicate to users?

I'm envisioning a splash screen which functions in a similar way to a splash screen inside a web-app.

Comment: Not so much a splash screen but you can customize the page a few ways where  you could place that information here are a couple links 1) https://github.com/Esri/ago-admin-wiki/wiki/Resources 2) https://github.com/Esri/ago-admin-wiki/wiki/Home-Page-Tweaks